# C++ Debug Assertion Fails Only With VPTR

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management

I'm wondering why I get an exception on the `delete` part in one case here, but not in the other.

### No exception case

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    ~A() { cout << "A dtor" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int x;
    ~B() { cout << "B dtor" << endl; }
};


A* f() { return new B; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(B) << " " << sizeof(A) << endl;
    A* bptr= f();
    delete bptr;
}
```

Herethe output is `4 1 .. A dtor`, since A has 1 byte for identity and B has 4 because of `int x`.

### Exception case

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    ~A() { cout << "A dtor" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B dtor" << endl; }
};


A* f() { return new B; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(B) << " " << sizeof(A) << endl;
    A* bptr= f();
    delete bptr;
}
```

Here the output is `4 1 .. A dtor`, since A has 1 byte for identity and B has 4 because of the `vptr` that's needed for its virtual destructor.
**But then a debug assertion fails inside the `delete` call (`_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID`)**.

### Environment

I'm running Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 SP1Rel.

Comment: Have you tried making the dtor of `A` virtual? This is required since you are calling `delete` on an `A*`.

Comment: [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/364jTa$1) runs the second code w/o exceptions, even it's not correct code, because `A`'s d-tor should be `virtual`

Comment: Try printing the original B pointer and the A pointer and see if they are different.  I suspect that they will be different with VC++.  They are the same with g++, and there is no exception with g++.

Comment: @VaughnCato They will be the same because it's a basic language guarantee.

Comment: @borisbn In VC++, it only asserts in debug mode, not in release. g++ does not use any debug-specific libraries by default, like VC++ does (in debug mode). Question is what would `valgrind` have to say about it.

Comment: @YamMarcovic: Which guarantee is that?  If A contained any data members, then the B pointer and A pointer would certainly be different.  In g++ they are the same when A is empty, which I believe is due to the empty base class optimization, but I don't think this is guaranteed.

Comment: @VaughnCato I don't think I understand what you mean by `A pointer` and `B pointer`, then. Are you talking about the value returned by `f()` and the variable I put it into inside `main()`?

Comment: @YamMarcovic: f() is still returning a value of type `A*`.  I'm talking about the `B*` value, before it is converted to an `A*`.  i.e. `A *f() { B *bp = new B; cerr << bp; return bp; }`

Comment: @VaughnCato I see your point now. I'll test it when I get home.

Comment: @VaughnCato `If A contained any data members, then the B pointer and A pointer would certainly be different.` Quite a clever point, I might add. :) Gives me some hope. Thanks.

Comment: @VaughnCato You are indeed correct in you assumption. `f()` returns an offset into B, and obviously that address isn't registered, thus `delete` fails. Please post it as a full answer, so I can accept it. :) Thanks! P.S even though I know the cause (why it has to offset in case of a vptr but not in case of an int - because vptr usually goes *first*, still, I wish your answer will include this rationale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are deleting an object whose static type is different from its dynamic type, and since the static type doesn't have a virtual destructor, you get undefined behavior.  This includes the behavior of sometimes working and sometimes not working as you are seeing.  However, I think you are interested in a little deeper understanding of what is happening with your particular compiler.

Class `A` has no members at all, so its data layout ends up looking like this:

```
struct A {
};
```

Since class `B` derives from class `A`, class `A` becomes embedded within B.  When class `B` has no virtual functions, the layout ends up looking like this:

```
struct B {
  A __a_part;
  int x;
};
```

The compiler can convert a `B*` to an `A*` by just taking the address of `__a_part`, as if the compiler had a function like this:

A* convertToAPointer(B* bp) { return &bp->__a_part; }

Since `__a_part` is the first member of `B`, the `B*` and the `A*` point to the same address.

Code like this:

```
A* bptr = new B;
delete bptr;
```

Is effectively doing something like this:

```
// Allocate a new B
void* vp1 = allocateMemory(sizeof(B));
B* bp = static_cast<B*>(vp1);
bp->B(); // assume for a second that this was a legal way to construct

// Convert the B* to an A*
A* bptr = &bp->__a_part;

// Deallocate the A*
void* vp2 = ap;
deallocateMemory(vp2);
```

In this case, `vp2` and `vp1` are the same.  The system is allocating and deallocating the same memory address, so the program runs without an error.

When class `B` has a virtual member function (the destructor in this case).  The compiler adds a virtual table pointer, so class B ends up looking like this:

```
struct B {
  B_vtable* __vptr;
  A __a_part;
};
```

The issue here is that `__a_part` is no longer the first member, and the `convertToAPointer` operation will now change the address of the pointer, so `vp2` and `vp1` no longer point to the same address.  Since a different memory location is being deallocated than the one that was allocated, you get the error.

Comment: Reviewing this, my error was indeed the assumption that the cast was a reinterpret_cast, when in actuality it was a static_cast.

Answer (score 3):

See [this post](http://code4thought.wordpress.com/tag/inheritance/)

A quick summary:

- You are telling the machine to delete an instance of A
- As this is a class which we call through pointer/reference maybe we should use a virtual table (VT)?
- There is no virtual members in A thus no VT is used
- We call the standard destructor of A…
- Bang! We are trying to delete class A but it happens that the pointer
  has lead us to object of B which contains VT which A didn't know of.
  sizeof(A) is 1 (as AFAIK it’s not legal to have size equal 0) and
  sizeof(B) is 4 (due to presence of VT). We wish to delete 1 byte, but
  there is a block of 4 bytes. Due to DEBUG heap monitoring, the error
  was caught.

The solution of course is to declare the base class's (`A`'s) `dtor` as `virtual` so `B`'s `dtor` will always be called.

EDIT: For the first case, here's what the standard has to say:

> §5.3 In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, **the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the
>   static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined**. In the second alternative (delete
>   array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

So both cases lead us to the realm of undefined behavior which of course differs from one implementation to the other. But it stands to reason that for most implementations the first case is easier to handle or at least easier to contemplate than the second which is just an esoteric anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't see how this explains the part where B contains an int, and is still 4 bytes, but no assertion fails.